# Can OVERLAPPED member InternalHigh be trusted as output after an overlapped Read or Write?

Tags: winapi

Doing some testing.  After an overlapped Write I use the `OVERLAPPED` members to set the Position.

```
bool MyWriteTestClass::PositionViaOverlapped(const OVERLAPPED *OVL) 
{
LARGE_INTEGER Pos ;
Pos.LowPart  =  OVL->Offset ;
Pos.HighPart =  OVL->OffsetHigh ;
Pos.QuadPart += OVL->InternalHigh ;

return SetFilePointerEx(File, Pos, &Pos, FILE_BEGIN) ;
}
```

PS. `Offset` and `OffsetHigh` were obviously properly set before the Write was executed

Per the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-overlapped `InternalHigh` contains the bytes transferred:

> The number of bytes transferred for the I/O request. The system sets
>   this member if the request is completed without errors.

However following sentence is scary

> The InternalHigh member was originally reserved for system use and **its behavior may change**.

I'm fairly sure `GetOverlappedResult()` uses `InternalHigh` to return the amount of bytes transferred, and as such I cannot imagine `InternalHigh` ever getting different meaning.

Still .. Interested to find out what you think ?

Comment: yes, `InternalHigh` is corresponded to `Information` member of [`IO_STATUS_BLOCK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_io_status_block) and this will be always. if you not afraid use undocumented - can use it if need. but for what you use `SetFilePointerEx` ?! this call is absolute senseless

Comment: @RbMm "*this call is absolute senseless*" - maybe the `File` is different than the one associated with the `OVERLAPPED`? Maybe that `File` is not using Overlapped I/O? You don't know, so that comment was really unnecessary.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - at first `SetFilePointerEx` **always** senseless and atavism, even if file use synchronous I/O - always better direct pass byte offset in read/write call instead save it first inside `FILE_OBJECT`. then if `File` the same file for which `OVL` correspond - this is double senseless - when we pass pointer to `OVERLAPPED` - used byte offset from it and ignored inside `FILE_OBJECT` (*The file pointer set by this function is not used for overlapped read and write operations.*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any native asynchronous api I/O call take pointer to [`IO_STATUS_BLOCK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_io_status_block). this is out parameter - when I/O finished it will be filled from kernel if api return not [`NT_ERROR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/using-ntstatus-values) status. because this [`IO_STATUS_BLOCK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_io_status_block) memory must be valid until I/O not finished. win32 level pass pointer to [`OVERLAPPED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-overlapped) in place pointer of [`IO_STATUS_BLOCK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_io_status_block). so it filled by kernel like [`IO_STATUS_BLOCK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_io_status_block).

`Internal` (more exactly it low 32-bit) containing final status of operation - correspond to `Status`

`InternalHigh` is correspond to `Information`.

however in most case when you use win32 layer you not need by self access `Internal` and especially  `InternalHigh` members. the api which give back pointer to `OVERLAPPED` to you 
 or check/wait on it (`GetOverlappedResult`, `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`, `LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE`, `PTP_WIN32_IO_CALLBACK` ) - already pass to you `NumberOfBytesTransferred` (however most 32 api (except `PTP_WIN32_IO_CALLBACK`) return it as 32bit `ULONG` and ignore high 32 bit on 64bit system (if this is IOCTL driver can return 64bit value inside `Information` ( or if want `InternalHigh` )

---

also i can note that `MyWriteTestClass::PositionViaOverlapped` is senseless. never exist sense call [`SetFilePointerEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointerex) or [`ZwSetInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwsetinformationfile) with [`FilePositionInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_position_information) - all what do this api - save byte offset inside [`FILE_OBJECT.CurrentByteOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_object) . at this member is used only for file opened for synchronous I/O and if user not provide explicit *ByteOffset* (via `OVERLAPPED`). always better for synchronous I/O provide explicit *ByteOffset* (simple not need do extra and expensive call to kernel). in case asynchronous I/O - always mandatory provide explicit *ByteOffset*  (or api fail wit error invalid parameter) and offset in `FILE_OBJECT` will be ignored.

so if you use asynchronous I/O on file - The file pointer set by this function is not used for read and write operations. if you use synchronous I/O - anyway this is extra call - better use direct byte offset inside `OVERLAPPED`

---

inside `MyWriteTestClass` need have member

`LARGE_INTEGER CurrentByteOffset;`

and inside `MyWriteTestClass::PositionViaOverlapped` need do

```
CurrentByteOffset.QuadPart += dwNumberOfBytesTransfered;
```

where `dwNumberOfBytesTransfered` taken form `OVL->InternalHigh` direct or better indirect (all win32 api which work with `OVERLAPPED` return this member (however how say usually as `ULONG` but not `ULONG_PTR`)

and when you need say write to file use

```
OVL->Offset = CurrentByteOffset.LowPart;
OVL->OffsetHigh = CurrentByteOffset.HighPart;
```

in general you need maintain file offset be self exactly in same class/struct where you maintain file handle. this more efficient compare maintain offset inside `FILE_OBJECT` in case synchronous file object and mandatory in case asynchronous file

Comment: I understand what you're saying wrt setting the position, but there are scenarios where it makes sense (at least for the time being) and as such I wanted to understand the deeper mechanics and the risk of using `InternalHigh`

Comment: @Peter - i personally on 100% sure that no any risk use `InternalHigh` and this never changed. native api require pointer to `IO_STATUS_BLOCK`. win32 layer place `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` at begin of `OVERLAPPED`. simply no another solution. possible say allocate memory block where place `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` and pointer to `OVERLAPPED` and inside `OVERLAPPED` save pointer to this.. but what sense ?! only native solution which used now. but let me ask - from where you tale `OVL` pointer ? why you at just not got and `dwNumberOfBytesTransfered` here ?

Comment: *but there are scenarios where it makes sense* i am sure that no. not exist. and if you use asynchronous I/O for  `File` - this is **double** no sense - it anyway will be not used. you need have `LARGE_INTEGER ByteOffset` or `ULONG64 ByteOffset` member inside `MyWriteTestClass` class and do `ByteOffset +=  dwNumberOfBytesTransfered `. but never `SetFilePointerEx`

Comment: in an ideal world I'm sure you're right.  But things are hardly ever ideal and sometimes one seeks an easy solution to bridge the gap until there is time again to make things better.  Especially when working on an old project, there is not always the luxury of a fresh start.  In my case I'm changing a synchronous write process into a semi-asynchronous write process.  The old design did not set position because the file object managed that but now that I use the OVERLAPPED approach I needed to 'fix' that by setting position explicitely, since Position is also used to set the Offset etc.

Comment: So yes, more expensive than needs to be, but that is nothing compared to the time needed to read and write, so neglectable in the bigger scheme of things. It is always tempting to optimize to the max possible, but it is not always necessary or noticeable.  Reading is now done using 2 alternating buffers, *during* the writing, which is where the real gain is.

Comment: @Peter - i bad understand now your problems without code. if you pass `OVERLAPPED` pointer to read/write call - offset is taken from it and all what you set via `SetFilePointerEx` anyway **ignored**. really how i say you need add `LARGE_INTEGER _ByteOffset;` to your class. you even can write member function with same name `MyWriteTestClass::SetFilePointerEx` wich will be change `_ByteOffset` member instead call win32 api with this name

Comment: @Peter *Reading is now done using 2 alternating buffers, during the writing, which is where the real gain is.* dont know your task of course but possible allocate single buffer - like circle buffer and do `ReadFileScatter` to it until exist free space and `WriteFileGather` from it. possible and make 100% circle buffer (by map memory section 2 time in adjacent areas of memory). another question if this big legacy code, not new dessign